# Buying games on the PlayStation Store without a credit card

Tags: psn

Is it possible to buy games, on the PlayStation Store, without a credit card?

Something similar to Google play credits. You could use it to pay for something without charging your credit card.

I've read about PlayStation Plus, but it only appears to offer some free games, and greater discounts on games from the PlayStation Store.

Comment: Don't quote me on this - but I believe they have PS+ "credit" cards (can't remember their actual name). You can often find them in Game stores or Supermarkets. Similar to the Xbox or iTunes gift cards.